# Cannot test for exceptions in F# using xUnit

Tags: f#, xunit

Here is the code:

```
module Tests

open System
open Xunit

[<Fact>]
let ``Simple Test`` () =
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(failwith "Error")
```

This fails to compile with:

```
error FS0041: A unique overload for method 'Throws' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Known type of argument: 'a  Candidates: - Assert.Throws<'T when 'T :> exn>(testCode: Action) : 'T - Assert.Throws<'T when 'T :> exn>(testCode: Func<Threading.Tasks.Task>) : 'T - Assert.Throws<'T when 'T :> exn>(testCode: Func<obj>) : 'T
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error message tells u, you need an action or a function that throws an exception, not an exception itself (I think). try "fun _ -> failwith "Error""

Comment: ah stupid me...I use xunit, but ironically only with C#, it wants a Func<T> not an fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looking for an Action or a Func, you CAN use a F# lambda and the compiler will implicitly create a Func for you.

```
module Tests

open System
open Xunit

[<Fact>]
let ``My test`` () =
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(
        fun () -> 
            (failwith "Error") :> obj)
```

you have to cast the output in this example to tell compiler what the return type of the function is (it could be anything, as it returns nothing)

Comment: Thanks! I think it was the upcasting that was tripping me up.

Comment: Having said that, this is really annoying code. Is there a better approach with xUnit or should I move to something like fsunit?

Comment: personally i write tests in C# in xunit (mainly to keep my C# skills ticking over). I'm thinking of moving to F# and xunit!....as a first step before possibly trying another test framework.

Comment: I would suggest sticking with xUnit and writing a few helpers to help you deal with the annoying cases. xUnit has the pretty big advantages that everyone knows it and that it's the best supported testing framework on .NET.